# Updating a Control after a property value changed from the Properties window

Tags: c#, wpf

I've created a new WPF UserControl and I added a new property but when I update the property in the Properties windows the control's UI isn't updated immediately, how can I force the control to repaint once a custom property is updated?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a PropertyChangedHandler to the DependencyProperty definition that updates the instance in the `sender` parameter.

Comment: Hi @slaks, I'm new in WPF and I don't understand what you say. Can you send me a link with an example or a tutorial explaining that step by step?